# Can page object model can be used if I want to use two appium driver in my test framework?

Tags: appium

Can page object model can be used if I want to use two appium driver in my test framework? In single test I need to manage two mobile device (dependent devices ). Can I use page object model as test framework in this case?

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You can run two app with single appium driver. You need to define appium driver as static.

Answer (score 0):

It can, but when using a page object model with multiple browsers, whether it be mobile or web, take care to not define your WebElements as static.  I recently worked with making an existing framework using Cucumber, TestNG, and Selenium/Appium run tests in parallel.  It would fail at inconsistent places.  It turned out the culprit was that the page elements were defined as static.

I was taught to avoid static declarations wherever possible (and sometimes you can't avoid it, but...) so my page objects always avoided that.  What was going on was that the page elements were tied to the class itself instead of each instantiation of the class.

There's a bit more to making tests run in parallel, but for multiple instances of Appium, that's the one thing pertaining to page objects that I would specifically bring to your attention.